# htaccess: Check whether the Server is executing PHP as CGI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, cgi

Is there a way to restrict destrictives in a `.htaccess` file to be only executed when the server is running PHP (or something else) as CGI?

Something similiar to this maybe?:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # directives
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So, I suppose this is not possible and it was a stupid question?